NullPointerException（java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration.createCompatibleVolatileImage(int, int, int)） when using JCEF in IntelliJ IDEA
I'm encountering a NullPointerException while using the Java Chromium Embedded Framework (JCEF) in IntelliJ IDEA. The error occurs during the rendering process, specifically when calling createCompatibleVolatileImage in the JBCefOsrHandler.onPaint method.
Here’s the full stack trace:
2024-12-17 08:13:54,043 [1104817161] INFO - STDERR - java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration.createCompatibleVolatileImage(int, int, int)" because the return value of "javax.swing.JComponent.getGraphicsConfiguration()" is null 
2024-12-17 08:13:54,043 [1104817161] INFO - STDERR - at com.intellij.ui.jcef.JBCefOsrHandler.onPaint(JBCefOsrHandler.java:132) 
2024-12-17 08:13:54,043 [1104817161] INFO - STDERR - at jcef/org.cef.CefClient.onPaint(CefClient.java:865)

Restart Idea to restore normal operation, but it may reappear

Can you share which version of IDEA you are using? A minimal sample reproduction project on GitHub might be helpful.

24.1，but I haven't encountered this problem again now

Thanks for the update. If it happens again, feel free to contact JetBrains support.

Make sure you use latest stable versions of packages.
It appears to be fixed in
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IJPL-955/NPE-Cannot-invoke-GraphicsConfiguration.createCompatibleImage-because-the-return-value-of-getGraphicsConfiguration-is-null-on
